# get results of primary key table from foreign key table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate and trying to use Criteria.
I stuck in getting the results from 2 table ie table where primary-foreign key are in realtion.

I have Carpooler and SourceToDestinationDetails DTO, Now based on user search data I want to fill Carpooler Object, which contain SourceToDestinationDetails, but I am not getting it and don't know how to do it using Criteria API.

```
public class Carpooler implements Serializable{

    private long carpoolerId;
    private String drivingLicenceNumber=null;
    private String userType=null;![enter image description here][1]
    private User user=null;
    private List<VehicleDetails> listOfVehicleDetails=null;
    private List<SourceToDestinationDetails> listOfSourceToDestinationDetails=null;
    private Date carpoolerCreationDate;
}

public class SourceToDestinationDetails implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7158985673279885525L;

    private long sourceToDestinationId;
    private String sourcePlace=null;
    private String destinationPlace=null;
    private String inBetweenPlaces=null;

    private String sourceLeavingTime=null;
}
```

[image]
[image]
This is what I wrote,

```
Criteria criteria1 = getSession().createCriteria(SourceToDestinationDetails.class);
criteria1.add(Restrictions.like("sourcePlace", "%" + from + "%"));
criteria1.add(Restrictions.like("destinationPlace", "%" + to + "%"));
List<SourceToDestinationDetails> listOfExactMatchCarpooler = criteria1.list();
```

through above Criteria API, I am only getting SourceToDestinationDetails DTO record, but now I need Carpooler record as well, I dont know how to get Carpooler record of matching Carpooler_id in SourceToDestinationDetails table.

I mean if user gives,

```
String from = "Bellandur";
    String to = "Silk Board";
```

then result should be `List<Carpooler>` object, which contain all matching SourceToDestinationDetails list inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by [Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/). You can use [@OneToMany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) annotation in your *SourceToDestinationDetails* class as below,

```
public class SourceToDestinationDetails implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7158985673279885525L;
    @Column
    private long sourceToDestinationId;
    @Column
    private String sourcePlace=null;
    @Column
    private String destinationPlace=null;
    @Column
    private String inBetweenPlaces=null;
    @Column
    private String sourceLeavingTime=null;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carpooler_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Carpooler> carpoolers;
}
```

If you want to acheive the same thing using *HIBERNATE XML*. Declare the XML as below

```
  <set name="carpoolers" table="source_destination" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="carpooler_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.test.Carpooler" />
    </set>
```

In that case your model class will be

```
public class SourceToDestinationDetails implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7158985673279885525L;

    private long sourceToDestinationId;
    private String sourcePlace=null;
    private String destinationPlace=null;
    private String inBetweenPlaces=null;

    private String sourceLeavingTime=null;
    private Set<StockDailyRecord> carpoolers = 
                new HashSet<StockDailyRecord>();
}
```

I usually prefer Annotations than ugly XML's

Comment: I am already using hbm.xml file for mapping, but my question is do I need to add  private Set<Carpooler> carpoolers;  in SourceToDestinationDetails as my Carpooler is already having List<SourceToDestinationDetails> property?